# What URL to use when creating a user through my Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am working on an API for my user model in rails. I have following Ryan Bates conventions laid out in his [API Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=api) for versioning and securing an API. Here are the relevant files:

## app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @user = User.new
      end
      def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @user.save
            format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
          else
            format.json  { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

## config/routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
...
      resources :users
    end
  end
```

Now I am trying to test out creating a new user via the API either through the browser or through curl, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm spitballing and thinking it should be something like...

```
api/v1/users/new?email="misats@wintas.com"?password="mypass"?password_confirmation="mypass"
```

...with that url I get a routing error No route matches [GET] "/new", so I'm guessing a need a post route? Any help or pointers in the right direction appreciated.

## Update

I added this route...

```
match 'create_user' => 'users#create'
```

..and now I can do...

```
api/v1/create_user?email="misats@wintas.com"?password="mypass"?password_confir‌mation="mypass"
```

...and I get this error...

```
 MultiJson::LoadError in Api::V1::UsersController#create

JSON::ParserError

Rails.root: /home/johnmlocklear/railsApps/dca_dummy
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Request

Parameters:

{"email"=>"\"misats@wintas.com\"?password=\"mypass\"?password_confir‌mation=\"mypass\"",
 "format"=>"json"}
```

## Update

OK, I'm realized I was going down the wrong path with this. I was trying to test this out in a browser. I realize I should be doing this with something like curl. I am trying this...

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user":{"email":"mistas@wintas.com","password":"mypass","password_confirmation":"mypass"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users
```

...and in the console I am seeing this...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `call' for #<User:0x9ed8614>):
  app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: query string starts with ? and then each param goes separated by &, you are using ? always

Comment: also, don't use match, use only post, you won't be able to test it with a query string since that is a get request, but GET is wrong for what you are doing

Comment: @arieljuod Not sure how to add a post to my route???

Comment: "resources :users" already creates a url with post method for users#create, just post to "/api/users", check all your routes with "rake routes", you can do "post 'create_user' => 'users#create'" but "resources :users" should handle that already

Comment: also, I see you are trying to test it using a browser or curl, why don't you try using rspec? that would be so much better

Comment: See update above. I'm now using a curl command.

Comment: I would still test this with rspec first, but curl is better than the webrowser. Line 8 is @user = User.new(params[:user])? it makes no sense that it calls "call" for user. Try using rspec, you can better inspect the code, add puts to print the current status of variables and then you have your tests for the controller which you should do anyway to have your app tested. Maybe params[:user] has some wrong value, it's hard to tell, try with rspec and I bet you get better results

Comment: Figured it out. I just had some bad syntax in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do this through browser which was wrong. Inherently most calls done by pasting in a URL are http 'get' calls. I ended up using this curl command...

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user":{"email":"mistas@wintas.com","password":"mypass","password_confirmation":"mypass"}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users
```

...which creates a user via http 'post'.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a post create request:

`api/v1/users/create?#{whatever parameters you want to pass}`

`'api/v1/users/new'` will only work as a get request and will give you a empty template of the user object.

You can run `rake routes` command to see the list of routes and their types

Comment: Thanks. Running 'rake routes' gave me http://pastie.org/9080255 but still not sure about what my format/syntax should look like.

Comment: When I create a user via views I get this http://pastie.org/9080293. Based on those params I tried http://pastie.org/9080281 but I get a routing error.

Comment: You can post like this `api/v1/users#create?email="misats@wintas.com"?password="mypass"?password_confirmation="mypass"`

Comment: I'm getting the error The action 'index' could not be found for Api::V1::UsersController with that url.

Comment: Modified routes to add match 'create_user' => 'users#create' and now I get  MultiJson::LoadError in Api::V1::UsersController#create

JSON::ParserError

Comment: @Lumbee you dont have to use 'from_json' , you can just say `User.new(params)`